# Contains operator in Oracle db doesn't show words with *&?^$# characters

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, contains

I have a table in oracle DB with a column called Name having these values.

```
    Hello$world
    Hello?world
    Hello*world
    Hello.world
```

When I do a search for the word *Hello* using CONTAINS operator this way I do not see any of these words in the results. Is my query style incorrect or does CONTAINS not search for these kind of words ?

```
SELECT * from t_words WHERE Contains(name, '%Hello%') > 0
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up `LIKE` syntax with `CONTAINS` syntax (but I have never used the latter so I may be wrong. I assume this must be `WHERE Contains(name, 'Hello') > 0`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The same query style works if I have words, "Hello_world" , "Hello world" in that column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SCORE(1), p.name FROM person p
WHERE CONTAINS(p.name, '%Hello%',1) > 0
```

it works when I do [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f242bd8a90b15b09b3ab1f8433aeac2).